# Raspberry Pi 2 boots but crashes after a random amount of time

Tags: crash

My RPi2 boots fine, but after some time, which can be anywhere between 15 minutes and 6 hours, it crashes, leaving both the ACT and PWR leds on. My wifi card's led is either off or stuck after the crash. Also, the crash only seems to occur while I am not using the Pi, it has never happened while I was using SSH.

`/var/log/syslog`:

```
Oct 10 12:17:54 raspberrypi mysqld: InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
Oct 10 12:17:54 raspberrypi mysqld: InnoDB: buffer...
Oct 10 12:17:54 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[2647]: Service "raspberrypi" (/services/udisks.service) successfully established.
Oct 10 16:49:59 raspberrypi mysqld: 151010 16:49:59  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
```

It crashed at 12:17:54.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't in power-saving mode?

Comment: @Sojan, It is not, because power-saving mode does not force the ACT led to stay on and halt all of my running programs.

Comment: right. Have you tried another SD Card/reinstalling Raspbian?

Comment: @Sojan, yep, a different sd runs fine, it must be one of my running programs, maybe mysql or apache2?

Comment: @Sojan I have updated my question with the last two entries in /var/log/syslog

Comment: can you try it without mysql running?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30117/discussion-between-patrick-cook-and-shojan).